# Optimizing pagination query with Seek Method

Tags: mysql, sql, pagination, query-optimization

This seems to be a very common question but did not get the solution for all the cases.

I have searched lots of articles to optimize the pagination query in MYSQL, I found the [Seek Method](https://blog.jooq.org/2013/10/26/faster-sql-paging-with-jooq-using-the-seek-method/) as the best solution.

But in every example of seek method, I found that order by clause on either number or date type fields, What if we are ordering by a varchar type column(eg: first_name)  which may contain blank and null values too, I tried (first_name, id) < (null, 15) AND (first_name, id) < ('', 15) which show uncertain result.

Please suggest how can we handle these cases too in seek method.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter which types of columns you use to order the rows, as long as they are "sortable" by the database. This includes pretty much all numbers, varchars, dates/times, etc.

The common exception are heavy data fields such as `BLOB`, `CLOB`, `BINARY`, etc. This list is very database-specific, so check which data types can participate in an `ORDER BY` in your database.

Also, please note that to use the Seek Method correctly the list of columns you use to order must produce a unique key. Otherwise, the pagination may work "funny".

Comment: `BLOB` and `BINARY`, too, are 'sortable' in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
    WHERE (first_name, id) < ('', 15)
```

Is nifty syntax *but performance sucks*!  The optimizer does not know how to use any index to help with such.  You *must* turn it into a complex `AND` and `OR` expression.  *And* you must have `INDEX(first_name, id)` in *that* order.

As for the expression, etc, the details are spelled out [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).

PS, don't use `first_name < NULL`; `NULL` compared to anything is always `FALSE`.  For example:

```
mysql> SELECT 'Rick' < NULL, 'Rick' > NULL, 'Rick' = NULL, 'Rick' != NULL;
+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+
| 'Rick' < NULL | 'Rick' > NULL | 'Rick' = NULL | 'Rick' != NULL |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+
|          NULL |          NULL |          NULL |           NULL |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+
```

(And `NULL` works like `FALSE` when tested in a `WHERE`.)

Answer (score 0):

Along with the usage of NULL there is another issue that is not yet pointed out by any answer.

You can't use that syntax with MySQL. 
Example: (first_name, id) < ('Alex', 15)

This is called “row values” syntax. Even if you don't use NULL and give a proper value, MySQL understands it but isn't able to use index in a proper way to produce the desired sort order and hence you aren't seeing results you expect.

Even though the row values syntax is part of the SQL standard, only a few databases support it. SQL Server 2017 does not support row values at all. The Oracle database supports row values in principle, but cannot apply range operators on them (ORA-01796). MySQL evaluates row value expressions correctly but cannot use them as access predicate during an index access. DB2 (only LUW, since 10.1) and PostgreSQL (since 8.4), however, have a proper support of row value predicates and uses them to access the index if there is a corresponding index available.

Good resource on this topic: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page